# Support ASP.Net Forms authentication in native mobile app

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, security, forms-authentication

Years ago, I built a web forms site that uses ASP.Net Forms Authentication. Now, we need to build a native mobile app (IOS/Android) that authenticates users with the same credentials they set on on the web.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, need to create web service for that and by calling webservice for Authentication from android/iphone...[Refer this link](http://osmosee.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/calling-a-json-based-asp-net-web-service-from-an-android-phone/)

Comment: One of the issues with .Net forms is the header payload, it's a real pain to be honest. It's been a long time since i've used .Net forms, but i do recollect that the server expects the header or it will throw an error. I guess you could try and parse the header and send it back. Although, this may end up being more trouble than it's worth. I would suggest writing services for authentication.

Comment: SO is getting too critical on questions. The point is to help the community learn. Not be elitist and stifle questions from being asked. All developers aren't on the same level. I've seen other users get this downvote response and, like them, I'm visiting stackoverflow less and less. Please consider an alternate method of handling these types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure but you most likely will want to build a RestFul service to do it. On iOS I would also recommend using AFNetworking or RestKit.